# Why libnotify stopped showing Rspec notifications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, guard, libnotify

I don't know why libnotify stoped showing informations about finished tests.
It shows Spork message: "Rspec successfully started." But after that does not show anything. I`m using Ubuntu.

```
guard 'spork', :cucumber => false, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
  watch('config/application.rb')
  watch('config/environment.rb')
  watch(%r{^config/environments/.+\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^config/initializers/.+\.rb$})
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')
  watch(%r{^spec/support/.+\.rb$})
end

guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :cli => "--drb", :all_on_start => false, :all_after_pass => false do
  watch(%r{^spec/.+_spec\.rb$})
  watch(%r{^lib/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/lib/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch('spec/spec_helper.rb') { "spec" }
  watch('spec/acceptance/acceptance_helper.rb') { "spec" }
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb$}) { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
  watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb$}) { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/acceptance/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^spec/support/(.+)\.rb$}) { "spec" }
  watch('config/routes.rb') { "spec/routing" }
  watch('app/controllers/application_controller.rb') { "spec/controllers" }
  # Capybara request specs
  watch(%r{^app/views/(.+)/.*\.(erb|haml)$}) { |m| "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }

  # watch(%r{^spec/support/(requests|controllers|mailers|models)_helpers\.rb}) { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}" }
  # watch(%r{^app/controllers/(.+)_(controller)\.rb}) { |m| ["spec/routing/#{m[1]}_routing_spec.rb", "spec/#{m[2]}s/#{m[1]}_#{m[2]}_spec.rb", "spec/requests/#{m[1]}_spec.rb"] }
  watch(%r{^app/(.+)\.rb}) { |m| "spec/#{m[1]}_spec.rb" }
end
```

My spec_helper: ***

When I initialize guard:

```
Running tests with args ["--color", "--format", "progress", "--format", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter::NotificationRSpec", "--out", "/dev/null", "--require", "/home/rege/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/guard-rspec-0.5.10/lib/guard/rspec/formatters/notification_rspec.rb", "spec"]...
```

How to diagnose where is the problem?

EDIT:

Solution: https://github.com/guard/guard-rspec/issues/90#issuecomment-3435651

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well and installed the guard-spork (https://github.com/guard/guard-spork) gem (added it to my rails Gemfile and bundle installed). Then, per the instructions on that page, I ran 'guard init spork' which adds a 'spork' section to your Guardfile for files you can watch.

When i ran bundle exec guard, it actually makes sure spork is also started and presto! my test file changes were getting run and the results posted to the notifier.  For the record, I use Ubuntu 11.10 64bit with ruby rvm. The relevant gems in my Gemfile were gem 'guard-rspec', gem 'guard-spork',   gem 'rspec-rails',     gem 'watchr',    gem 'spork',    gem 'libnotify'. Not sure if all are relevant.

You can find the step by step I used for this in Hartl's awesome Rails tutorial http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec:guard (sections 3.6.2 and 3.6.3).